# Why are my changesets removed if I close a project?

Tags: eclipse, svn, subversive, changeset

In Eclipse, I regularly close (rightclick on project -> close project) a subset of my projects for varying reasons.

I noticed that if there are changes in the closed project that are assigned to a given changeset, the changes become "< Unassigned >" when I open the project again.

This is extremely frustrating since it basically leaves me the following two options:

- never ever close a project with changes assigned to a changeset
- re-assign all changes in the project to the desired changeset after having re-opened the project

Why is this the case?

Is there a way around this?

Versions:  Eclipse 4.3.1, Subversive SVN Team Provider 1.1.1.I20130816-1700

Comment: what you mean by changeset is it working set.Add screen shot.

Answer (score 0):

you closed your project in eclipse, but, I am guessing your eclipse project is connected from your laptop to svn server. if so, you need to close repo for commits in svn - that will close your project in real.
there is an access file on svn server side - remove access for whoever you want to be cut off.
or... make it read-only access - they will be able to see the project, but won't be able to commit to it.